# Illegal Character Escape in Text.Smolder.Renderer.String.purs

Tags: purescript, purescript-pux

In an attempt to compile my program, I received the following error regarding the file String.purs from the Text.Smolder.Renderer module:

```
Error found:
at bower_components\purescript-smolder\src\Text\Smolder\Renderer\String.purs:76:
56 - 76:57 (line 76, column 56 - line 76, column 57)

  Unable to parse module:
  Illegal character escape code
```

I looked at the source file and found the following at line 76:

```
toStream s = foldr (\c t -> c :< (Just t)) (mkCofree '\0' Nothing) cs
```

How can this be corrected? (And how on earth could a **compiler** error be in a public library!!!)

Comment: Which compiler version are you using?

Comment: Compiler version 0.13.0

Comment: Ok, that checks out. 0.13 was only released a couple weeks ago (see [release notes](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases/tag/v0.13.0)), and it does have some breaking changes in the parser (and treatment of escaped characters is one of them), and not all libraries had the time to upgrade yet. I recommend downgrading to 0.12.5 for the time being.

Comment: Please I'm new to purescript. How do I downgrade safely?

Comment: How did you install the compiler in the first place?

Comment: npm install -g purescript

Comment: Its ok, I've found the way

Comment: `npm install -g purescript@0.13.0`